# Delay in web sockets execution (maybe) and a few other problems

Tags: c#, websocket, hangfire

My app is related to Binance and I'm using Binance.Net (from JKopf) as an API wrapper and Hangfire for cron job tasks at certain time intervals.

I have to perform three type of tasks:

- cron job tasks on finished candles (for all candles before the last one). For example, those are performed in the beginning of the next hour e.g. 11:00 pm with 1 second delay, because Binance sometimes delays the data.
- real time checks using web sockets. Basically, their API provides a stream only for the last candle only because it's the only one changing which is kinda obvious.
- scheduled tasks after 10 minutes when a condition is met. Look at `PerformInRealTimeLogicAsync` and `isTriggered`. When `isTriggered` is true, it is supposed to schedule another check after 10 minutes. If there aren't 10 minutes left by the end of the hour, it should perform the check in the last minute. For example, let's say the current time is 10:52 pm which means there aren't 10 minutes left. It should perform the check in the last minute before the next hour (10:59 pm). If the second 10-minute check returns false, it should schedule another task after another 10 minutes.

The main problem is that the web sockets logic (web sockets) is delaying i.e. it doesn't execute on time but with some delay and that the *10 minutes after* logic is not working properly.

Questions:

1. The logic to perform check 1 minute before the end when there aren't 10 minutes left, is not working.
2. Like I said above, the entire logic is delaying, somehow. It might be the `await Task.Delay(1000)`, I'm not sure.

I know it's delaying because it sometimes forgets to execute certain minutes.

```
Current time: 12/6/2019 12:41:00 AM
// note that there isn't 12:42:00, it forgot to execute it
Current time: 12/6/2019 12:43:00 AM
```

3. Currently I'm subscribing to the web sockets inside the cron job (`DoWork()`) and I think that's the problem for the delay. Is the right way to subscribe outside of the cron jobs and unsubscribe before the application stops.

```
/ Start a cron job on each hour
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("task{i}", () => DoWork(), "0 */1 * * *", TimeZoneInfo.Local);
await _socketClient.Unsubscribe(_subscription);

public void DoWork()
{
    ...

    // That delay is needed because Binance sometimes delays the new candles
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    var klines = await _binanceService.GetAllKlinesAsync();

    // Web sockets
    await PerformInRealTimeLogicAsync();

    ...
}

// Web sockets
private bool _isProcessing = false;

public void async Task PerformInRealTimeLogicAsync()
{
    var result = await _socketClient.SubscribeToKlineUpdatesAsync(symbol, interval, async data =>
    {
        if (!_isProcessing && Data?.Data.Close != data.Data.Close)
        {
            _isProcessing = true;
            Data = data;

            // First logic
            var result = await FirstLogicAsync();
            if (result)
            {
                _isProcessing = false;
                return;
            }

            // Second logic
            var isTriggered = await SecondLogicAsync();
            if (isTriggered)
            {
                // Wait 10 minutes and check again same condition
                double seconds = RemainingSecondsUntilNextHour();
                if (seconds <= 10 * 60)
                {
                    BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => DelayedJob(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds - (1 * 60)));
                }
                else
                {
                    BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => DelayedJob(), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
                }

                _isProcessing = false;
                return;
            }

            _isProcessing = false;
        }
    });

    if (result.Success)
    {
        _subscription = result.Data;
    }
}

private double RemainingSecondsUntilNextHour()
{
    var timeOfDay = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
    var nextFullHour = TimeSpan.FromHours(Math.Ceiling(timeOfDay.TotalHours));
    var delta = (nextFullHour - timeOfDay).TotalSeconds;
    return delta;
}

// Scheduled job
public void DelayedJob()
{
    if (condition)
    {
        // Conditions are met, so we stop
    }
    else
    {
        // Conditions are not met, so we schedule another job after another 10 minutes
        double seconds = RemainingSecondsUntilNextHour();
        if (seconds <= 10 * 60)
        {
            BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => DelayedJob(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds - (1 * 60)));
        }
        else
        {
            BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => DelayedJob(), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** The problem is that I always subscribe to the stream by calling `DoWork()` method on each time interval and I never unsubscribe it. Should I unsubscribe it in the last minute by the end of the hour?

Note that I still haven't fixed it, I just realized that this is one of the causes.

Answer (score -1):

Let's break down your concerns and tackle them one by one:

1. **Logic to perform a check 1 minute before the end when there aren't 10 minutes left is not working**:

   The logic looks correct at first glance. When the remaining seconds is less than or equal to 10 minutes (600 seconds), it schedules the job 1 minute before the next hour. If the logic isn't triggering as expected, you should verify that the value returned by `RemainingSecondsUntilNextHour()` is correct.
2. **Entire logic is delaying**:

   `await Task.Delay(1000);` will introduce a 1-second delay. If you're observing that it skips minutes occasionally, there may be other parts of your code that introduce delays (e.g., blocking calls or other intensive operations). Hangfire itself can introduce delays if the background job queue becomes overloaded.
3. **Subscribing to WebSockets inside CronJob**:

   It's a bad idea to keep subscribing to a WebSocket every hour without unsubscribing from the previous subscriptions. This will create a lot of open connections which can lead to all sorts of issues. Always make sure to unsubscribe from any previous WebSocket connections before subscribing again.

   It might be better to manage the WebSocket connection lifecycle separately from your job logic. Here's a potential solution:

   - **Subscribing**: Instead of subscribing inside your `DoWork()`, consider setting up the subscription when the application starts.
   - **Unsubscribing**: Set up a clean-up job that runs, for example, once a day to unsubscribe from any stale WebSocket connections. Alternatively, you can track the time of the last received message from a connection and unsubscribe if a certain duration passes without any new message.
4. **Fix regarding the repeated subscriptions**:

   Your realization is correct. Subscribing repeatedly without unsubscribing can lead to multiple WebSocket connections being open simultaneously. This could contribute to the delay in processing and may even lead to some messages getting dropped.

   To resolve this, you can:

   - **Unsubscribe from the WebSocket at the end of every hour**: This ensures that there's only one WebSocket connection at any given time.
   - **Implement a mechanism to detect inactive WebSocket connections**: For example, if no messages are received for a certain duration, treat the connection as inactive and unsubscribe.

Here's a potential revised approach:

1. Modify `DoWork()`:

```cs
public async Task DoWork()
{
    ...

    // Unsubscribe previous socket
    if (_subscription != null)
    {
        await _socketClient.Unsubscribe(_subscription);
        _subscription = null;
    }

    // That delay is needed because Binance sometimes delays the new candles
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    var klines = await _binanceService.GetAllKlinesAsync();

    // Web sockets
    await PerformInRealTimeLogicAsync();

    ...
}
```

2. Adjust the WebSocket logic to only subscribe if there's no active subscription:

```cs
public async Task PerformInRealTimeLogicAsync()
{
    if (_subscription != null) return;

    var result = await _socketClient.SubscribeToKlineUpdatesAsync(symbol, interval, async data =>
    {
        ...
    });

    if (result.Success)
    {
        _subscription = result.Data;
    }
}
```

With these changes, you will be unsubscribing from the WebSocket at the end of every hour and only subscribing if there's no active subscription. This will prevent the accumulation of multiple subscriptions. Remember to thoroughly test your code after these changes to ensure it works as expected.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541